# sql cutomize column name after different case when and group by conditions

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery

I have column1 with different values (a,b,c). I need to count each value in that column based on the values of column2 (1,2) and column3 (true,false).

At the end, I need to have an output column whose name if the name of the different combinations (numberof_a_and_1_and_true, numberof_a_and_1_and_false, numberof_a_and_2_and_true, numberof_b_and_2_and_true etc

how can I do that ? I thought about using countif but it is too long.

Comment: Add your sample and expected output data.

Comment: Why do you want to create new columns for each combination? You can already use group by for it.

Comment: @Samorix . . . Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1):

In BigQuery, you would use `countif()`:

```
select name,
       countif(col1 = 'a' and col2 = 1 and col3) as a_1_true,
       countif(col1 = 'a' and col2 = 1 and not col3) as a_1_false,
       countif(col1 = 'a' and col2 = 2 and col3) as a_2_true,
       countif(col1 = 'a' and col2 = 2 and not col3) as a_2_false,
       countif(col1 = 'b' and col2 = 1 and col3) as b_1_true,
       countif(col1 = 'b' and col2 = 1 and not col3) as b_1_false,
       countif(col1 = 'b' and col2 = 2 and col3) as a_b_true,
       countif(col1 = 'b' and col2 = 2 and not col3) as b_2_false,
       countif(col1 = 'c' and col2 = 1 and col3) as c_1_true,
       countif(col1 = 'c' and col2 = 1 and not col3) as c_1_false,
       countif(col1 = 'c' and col2 = 2 and col3) as c_2_true,
       countif(col1 = 'c' and col2 = 2 and not col3) as c_2_false
from t
group by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do this...

```
select column1
       ,count(case when column1='a' and column2=1 and column3=true then 1 end) 
       ,count(case when column1='a' and column2=2 and column3=true then 1 end) 
       ,count(case when column1='a' and column2=1 and column3=false then 1 end) 
       ,count(case when column1='a' and column2=2 and column3=false then 1 end)
       --Add similar conditions for column1=b and c
  from table 
group by column1
```